# You want Academia? Then look like Academia, to begin with

Tags: discussion, support, tags, site-policy

[An answer](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1847/61) by @Ubiquitous reminded me of a past discussion 3 years ago about [using the JEL classification system for tagging in economics.se](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/198/61)

I am bringing the issue up once more, and I make the following specific proposal:

**To start including in the tag label the JEL classification code, say "game-theory-jc-C7" or simply "game-theory-C7".**

For existing tags I am under the impression that the tag-name cannot be changed (**SE crew please clarify this, thank you**). If this is indeed the case, we would need to create the tag "game-theory-C7" and then make "game-theory" a synonym to the former.

As usual, answers are for elaboration and alternative proposals, while one can simply upvote ("agree") or downvote ("disagree") the question.

**UPDATE February 8th 2018**

Now that I have earned the Tumblweed badge for this post, ("Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week"), I guess we can put the whole "we want more Academia here" issue to rest.

Comment: Isn't academia all about publishing papers that no-one except yourself ever bothers to read (with a few exceptions)?  I think that makes this post as such all the more academic....